# Session lost when navigate to a new page via HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have HTML anchor tag as a button in my page. In page load I set the URL to the href property of that anchor tag. Before setting the href property, I save some information in an object and save that object in a session. That information is used in the new page that navigates after clicking that anchor tag.

When I navigate to the new page from clicking that particular anchor tag via HTTPS the session variable that I have set is persists. I can access the properties of the object that I set to that particular session.

But I navigate to the new page from clicking that particular anchor tag via HTTP, the properties of the object that I save in the session is lost.
Can anyone have idea about what’s going on? Why the session variables get lots when navigating to a new page via HTTP?

Comment: Many browsers have security restrictions, that allow you go to from less secure to more secure without any loss, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should write code like in aspx.cs page
 `if(!Ispostback) {session["variable"] = value;
Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx"); }`
after that nevigate to  another page

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use LinkButton instead of anchor tag and write the code on it's event somthing like this:

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Session["variable"] = yourobject; 
Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx"); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.
But my requirement is navigate to the new page without having a postback. That why I used anchor tag and set the href property when loading.
My high concern is how the session variables (properties of the session object) get lots only when navigating via only in HTTP.
Is this a known issue with session variables? Can anyone have any solution to persist the sessions variables when navigate to anew page via HTTP?